# Asymptotic behaviour of of $\sum_{n=0}^k a_n b_{k-n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, asymptotics, estimation

Let $(a_n)_n$ and $(b_n)_n$ be two sequences of positive numbers such that:

-$a_n\sim a/n^{3/2}$ for some $a>0$;

-$b_n\sim b/n^{3/2}$ for some $b>0$;

Is it true that as $k\to \infty$,

$\sum_{n=0}^k a_n b_{k-n}\sim \frac{1}{k^{3/2}}(a\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}b_n+b\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n) ?$

If not true, under what additional conditions the statement is true?

Comment: Some heuristics suggest that $$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^k {a_n b_{k - n} }  \sim \left( {a_0 b + b_0 a + 2ab\zeta \left( {\tfrac{3}{2}} \right)} \right)\frac{1}{{k^{3/2} }}
$$ as $k\to +\infty$.

Comment: I do not see why... at least in the case $a_n=a/n^{3/2}$ and $b_n=b/n^{3/2}$ my estimate should be correct.

Comment: In that special case, your estimate gives $$
\frac{1}{{k^{3/2} }}\left( {ab_0  + a\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{b}{{n^{3/2} }}}  + ba_0  + b\sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{a}{{n^{3/2} }}} } \right) = \left( {a_0 b + b_0 a + 2ab\zeta \left( {\tfrac{3}{2}} \right)} \right)\frac{1}{{k^{3/2} }},
$$ which is what I think holds in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's true that:  $\ \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^n a_k b_{n-k}\sim \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}(a\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}b_k+b\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_k) $

Here is a demonstration.

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^na_kb_{n-k} =t_n+u_n+v_n+w_n \quad $ with:

$t_n=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \root{3}\of{n}\rfloor}a_kb_{n-k}   \quad  , \quad u_n= \displaystyle \sum_{k=\lfloor \root{3}\of{n}\rfloor+1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor }a_kb_{n-k} \quad ,\quad v_n = \sum_{k=\lfloor n/2\rfloor +1}^{n-\lfloor \root{3}\of{n}\rfloor} a_kb_{n-k} \quad ,\quad w_n=\sum_{k=n-\lfloor \root{3}\of{n}\rfloor +1}^n a_kb_{n-k}$

- We know that there exists B such that $\ \forall n\geqslant 1 \ , \ b_n\leqslant \dfrac{B}{n^{3/2}}   $. Then $ \ \displaystyle u_n\leqslant \sum_{k= \lfloor \root{3}\of{n}\rfloor+1}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor }  a_k \dfrac{B}{(n-\lfloor n/2\rfloor)^{3/2}}   $.
  $\displaystyle 0\leqslant u_n\leqslant 2^{3/2}B \sum_{k=\lfloor \root{3}\of{n}\rfloor+1}^{+\infty}a_k \dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}} \quad $. So $\ u_n={\rm o}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$
- By the same idea  $\ v_n={\rm o}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$

$t_n-\displaystyle \dfrac{b}{n^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}a_k = x_n+y_n+z_n\quad   $ with

$x_n=\displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \root{3}\of{n}\rfloor} a_kb \left(\dfrac{1}{(n-k)^{3/2}}-\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}} \right)  , \quad y_n= \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \root{3}\of{n}\rfloor} a_k\left(b_{n-k}- \dfrac{b}{(n-k)^{3/2}}\right), \quad   z_n=-\dfrac{b}{n^{3/2}}\sum_{k=\lfloor \root{3}\of{n} \rfloor +1}^{+\infty} a_k $

- It's clear that $\ z_n={\rm o}\left(\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$
- $\displaystyle 0\leqslant x_n\leqslant \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \root{3}\of{n}\rfloor} a_kb \left(\dfrac{1}{(n-\lfloor \root{3}\of{n}\rfloor)^{3/2}}-\dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}} \right) \leqslant \dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}} \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}a_kb \left( \dfrac{1}{\left( 1- \frac{\lfloor \root{3}\of{n}\rfloor }{n}\right)^{3/2}}-1\right)\ $. So  $\ x_n={\rm o}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$
- $|y_n| \leqslant \displaystyle \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \root{3}\of{n}\rfloor} \dfrac{a_k}{(n-k)^{3/2}} \left| (n-k)^{3/2}b_{n-k}-b\right| \leqslant \dfrac{1}{(n-\root{3}\of{n})^{3/2}}\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}a_k \sup_{p\geqslant n-\lfloor \root{3}\of{n}\rfloor} |p^{3/2}b_p-b|\ $ .
  And  $\ y_n={\rm o}\left( \dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}}\right)$

So, we have  $\ t_n \sim \dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}} b\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} a_k$

With the same ideas $\ w_n \sim \dfrac{1}{n^{3/2}} a\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty} b_k$

And we can conclude (we may add the equivalents because they are positive).